# ipad app opens browser in the background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, background, sms

Im using the openURL command to send an SMS, but it opens the safari,
can I send the command so it opens in the background??

ie, the user dont see the browser opening or the message that it gives, and stays in the app,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://smsgw.exetel.com.au/sendsms/api_sms.php?username=xxx&password=xx&mobilenumber=0xxx&message=xxr&sender=mk&messagetype=Text&referencenumber=04"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];
```

Thank you

Comment: there is nothing as an "xcode app". xcode is an IDE only.

Comment: That sounds like it might be a bit evil, if it were possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have Safari open a URL for you in the background. But supposing you just want to request the URL and ignore whatever comes back, you could try:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"...whatever..."];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url delegate:nil];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request];
[connection start];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this be creating a [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadRequest%3a) inside your app, and calling `loadRequest:` on the instance, like this:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];

webView.delegate = self;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://smsgw.exetel.com.au/sendsms/api_sms.php?username=xxx&password=xx&mobilenumber=0xxx&message=xxr&sender=mk&messagetype=Text&referencenumber=04"];
NSUrlRequest *request = [[NSUrlRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

This will load the URL inside the app, without sending you over to Mobile Safari. The benefit of this method over `NSUrlConnection` is that if you conform to the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol and implement `webViewDidFinishLoad:` in your delegate class, you can see if the call succeeded or not.

Comment: I absolutely agree that if you want to catch errors, a web view is going to break things down more definitively. You can catch the various loading responses of an NSURLConnection (by supplying an actual delegate to the NSURLRequest), but then you need to inspect HTTP return codes (as, e.g., a 404 will usually also return a page) and monitor the connection status. A web view is probably more heavyweight, but it's extremely unlikely to be an issue.

Comment: +1 on your answer; It'll probably be exactly what he needs, in a lighter weight form.